# Nx Angular - 404 after refresh with PathLocationStrategy

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am working on creating an Nx monorepo workspace for Angular apps. I have a single sandbox app and am configuring routes for it.

My configuration is as follows:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NxWelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path       : 'welcome',
    component  : NxWelcomeComponent
  },
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome'}
];

const routeConfig: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
  useHash: false,
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routeConfig)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If I serve the app with `useHash: true` everything works as intended.

- Navigate to `/` redirects to `/welcome`
- Navigate to or refresh from `/welcome` reloads the page
- Navigate to any other path redirects to `/welcome`

However, when serving with `useHase: false` the only thing that works is navigating to `/` and if you refresh or try any other path it gives 404.

To my understanding I have configured everything correctly, and this PathLocationStrategy should be working. However, I have never worked with Nx before, so is there some kind of configuration I am missing that needs to be added to Nx in order to allow the local webserver to recognize the path strategy?

If it is just an issue with Nx serving the app locally and once built and deployed to our production server we can use path location, then im okay with doing something like:

```
const routeConfig: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
  useHash: !environment.production,
}
```

to use hash locally and path when deployed.

Comment: How are you running your app in local.

Comment: @saravana However Nx configures it by default. Im using incremental build/serve with ``nx serve sandbox --parallel`` and using the ``@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser`` executor for build and ``@nrwl/web:file-server`` for serve. Following their guides here: https://nx.dev/recipes/other/setup-incremental-builds-angular

Comment: The server which run the app ( either local or prod)  should handle it if we use pathlocation.  See the link https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration